# Get events where all occurrences are in the past with the Solspace Calendar plugin

Tags: plugin-calendar

With the [Solspace Calendar](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar) plugin, is there currently a way to pull a list of all events that don't have occurrences in the future?  In other words, we have a calendar with a lot of repeating events and we want to pull up a list of all of the events (not the occurrences) which are not longer actively repeating.  So until < today?

It seems like using the `dateRangeEnd` parameter lets you pull up only occurrences in that range but don't seem to know of a way to just get events that have stopped repeating?